# Ramified covers of 3-torus

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

It is known that every orientable 3-manfiold can be obtained as a ramified cover of S<sup>3</sup> with a ramification (of some order) at a link in S<sup>3</sup>. I am curious if there is a reasonable characterization of 3-manifolds that cover 3-torus?

Added. Notice that such a manifold is enlargeble, so it does not admit a metric of positive scalar curvature, so for example a connected sum of n  copies of S<sup>2</sup> x S<sup>1</sup> does not admit a ramified cover of T<sup>3</sup> (as far as I understand).

Comment: Any conjectures? Clearly there is an onto homomorphism $\pi_1M\to Z^3$; can you do better?

Comment: I don't really know anything about this question, and can not do better than the homeomorphism to Z^3. For every M^3 its connected sum with several T^3 admits a cover to T^3 :) 

Comment: Conjecture: M is a branched cover of T^3 iff the first homology group of M has rank at least three. 

Comment: (M assumed to be closed, orientable, connected.)

Comment: Could the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrization_conjecture help here by reducing to 8 Thurston geometries?

Comment: No, in fact I did not read the proof for S^3. Also the existence of onto homeo $\pi_1M\to Z^3$ as well having rank of first homology at lest 3 is no sufficient  because covers of T^3 don't admit a metric of positive scalar curvature, so the conncted sum of 3 S^2xS^1 will be a counterexample. 

Comment: Ok - Instead of M having homology of rank at least three, lets assume that M has, as a connect summand, an irreducible manifold with homology of rank at least three. How is that?

Comment: Ah, I don't think that having a connect summand with enough homology suffices.  I give up. 

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note that a branched covering induces an injection of rational cohomology rings, by transfer considerations. Therefore the cohomology of a manifold that is a branched covering of $T^3$ must contain three classes of degree 1 whose triple cup product is nontrivial.

This condition on a manifold $M^3$ implies the existence of a map $M^3\to T^3$ of nonzero degree. Passing to a covering space of $T^3$ if necessary we obtain such a map that is also surjective on $\pi_1$. Assuming the resulting map is of degree $\ge 3$, the main result of [Edmonds, Allan L.Deformation of maps to branched coverings in dimension three. Math. Ann. 245 (1979), no. 3, 273--279.] implies that this map is homotopic to a branched covering.