# Ramified covers of S^n

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, gn.general-topology

This question has been inspired by [covering 3-torus post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5546/ramified-covers-of-3-torus).

> Is it true that any good (smooth, compact, oriented) $n$-manifold can be mapped to $S^n$ in such a way that the map is true covering away from codimension 2?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.  See Feighn's short [note](http://www.raco.cat/index.php/CollectaneaMathematica/article/view/56965) "Branched covers according to J.W. Alexander".