# Branched Coverings of the $4$-sphere branched along a knotted surface

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

This question is related to, but apparently not exactly the same as,  [Ramified cover of the $4$-sphere.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8697/ramified-cover-of-4-sphere)  Piergallini, *et al.* have singular points on their branch loci.

Which closed orientable $4$-dimensional manifolds can be realized as simple branched coverings of $S^4$ branched along a knotted surface? By *knotted surface*, I mean a smooth embedding of a closed orientable (but not necessarily connected) $2$-dimensional manifold. By *simple* I mean if the covering has $n$-sheets, then along the knotted surface the cover has $n-1$ sheets. Thus on the singular sheet the covering is $2$-to-$1$, as $z\mapsto z^2$.

I am especially interested in the case when $n=2$ or $3$ in which I can give an explicit immersion thereof into $S^4\times D^2 \subset of S^6$ in which the projection is the covering map.

Comment: Look at the first Greg's comment here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8697/ramified-cover-of-4-sphere/8715#8715

Comment: @Anton, Thanks, the way I am reading their main statement is that the branching set is a locally flat PL surface. It is conceivable to me that the surface is immersed in S^4 rather than embedded. I might be missing something obvious. I'll think about this some more.


Comment: On the second page here http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0203087v2.pdf 
they say  

$$ $$

"In the next section we show how elimination of nodes can be performed up to
cobordism of coverings, after the original 4–fold covering has been stabilized by
adding a ﬁfth trivial sheet. This proves the following representation theorem."

Comment: OK, Now I understand. You are empowered to close the question, I think so please do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anton's comments above answer the question.